# Android: OutOfMemory Error setContextView

Tags: android, android-studio

I am experimenting with simple animation but the setContextView in MainActivity (Line 16 in the code below) is throwing an OutOfMemory error. I tried removing my onCreate() method code to see if it happened without it and the error still occurred.

```
 package com.example.ryan.firstanimation;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    animator = new ObjectAnimator();
    animator.addListener(listener);
    arrowView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upArrow);
    animator.setTarget(arrowView);
    firstLeft = arrowView.getLeft();
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            animator.start();

        }
    });

}

ImageView arrowView;
int firstLeft;

int left;
int right;
int top;
int bottom;
Button button;

Animator animator;
Animator.AnimatorListener listener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        left=arrowView.getLeft();
        right=arrowView.getRight();
        top = arrowView.getTop();
        bottom = arrowView.getBottom();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        animator.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        if (arrowView.getRight() < 360) {
            left++;
            arrowView.setLeft(left);
        } else{
            arrowView.setLeft(firstLeft);
        }
    }
};
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ryan.firstanimation.MainActivity"

>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start animation"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"
    android:id="@+id/upArrow"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's in your layout? Any large images?

Comment: I believe I minimized the image with layout_height,width but if that does not actually truncate the image, then yes it does contain a large image

Comment: That *scales* the image. That's why Android has resolution buckets. Scale and try again.

Comment: It was the image size, I tried a different, smaller image and it compiled.  I wish it just said so in the compiler. Thank you.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how much memory your device has.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!